# Attempts to tap a UIButton in a UITableViewCell using UI Automation fail with "could not be tapped"

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, instruments, ui-automation

I have an iPhone app that I'm testing using UI Automation.

I have a button in a `UITableViewCell` but when I try to tap on it using UI Automation I get the following error.

```
Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].elements()[element_name].tableViews()[0].elements().firstWithPredicate(name contains[c] 'Brooklyn').elements()["detailsButton"] could not be tapped
```

I have enabled accessibility on the button in Interface Builder and assigned the accessibility label (and identifier) "detailsButton".  I can retrieve the button element and have verified that it is valid.  I just can't tap it for some reason.

[image: UIATableCell Brooklyn]

The UIButton is a round rectangular button with user interaction enabled.  Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Have you tried setting a delay like target.delay(3); before tapping the button?

Comment: How about posting your code as well, not joust the error message.

Comment: I think it is an issue with respect to how the addition of the button to the tableviewcell has been done - Post the code for a better response

Comment: Can you post another pic with the UIATableCell expanded?

Answer (score 1):

You can alloc the `UIButton` except using round rect button. And also you can set target action of button in your controller class where table view delegate methods are presents.

Answer (score 1):

Try asserting first if the button exists, use [tuneup_js](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js) for easy assertions.
Then assert if the button is enabled.

Have you tried:
`target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].elements()[element_name].tableViews()[0].**cells()**.firstWithPredicate("name contains[c] 'Brooklyn'").elements()["detailsButton"]`?

Also post another picture which shows the UIATableCell expanded where the detailsButton exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `ButtonType=Custom`

Answer (score 0):

```
but=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

You must use a custom button type.

Comment: You should probably explain some more than just posting a single line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using UI Automation. But as much I know about adding `UIButton` in a tableviewcell-

1) just add UIButton in `UITableViewCell`. 
2) set `UIButton's` tag value and add target to that button. 
3) In the target button method, you can get the `UIButton` object and do your stuff over there..

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same problem. After I added the delay it works.

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch a tap event over the entire window:

```
function tap_from_window(elem) {
    var mainWindow = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
    var elemRect = elem.rect();
    var windowRect = mainWindow.rect();

    var xPos = (20 + elemRect.origin.x) / windowRect.size.width;
    var yPos  = (50 + elemRect.origin.y) / windowRect.size.height;

    mainWindow.tapWithOptions({tapOffset:{x:xPos, y:yPos}});    
}

var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var window = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow();
var tableView = window.scrollViews()[0].elements()[element_name].tableViews()[0];
tap_from_window(tableView.elements().firstWithPredicate(name contains[c] 'Brooklyn'))
```

Like many things related to iOS, I have no idea why the element cannot be tapped directly. I adapted the above function from the code in this post: [scrollToVisible error while testing on a device, UIAutomation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200893/scrolltovisible-error-while-testing-on-a-device-uiautomation)